# How to show a plot in Rstudio

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

In RStudio, I must have changed some setting regarding the display of a plot in the Plots box (perhaps using dev.off()). Anyway, as a result, I cannot display plots any more, even by logging out.
Examples:

```
x <- c(1:5)
y <- x
plot(x,y)
```

Result: no plot shown.

```
data <- c(109, 89, 4405,  574,  1663,  287,   271,  1786,   749,  2366)
hist(data,plot=TRUE)
```

No histogram displayed.

I know this seems like the most stupid question in the world, but it seems extremely difficult to find an answer.
For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292563/how-do-i-reset-the-graphical-parameters-back-to-default-values-without-use-of-de) they ask about restoring the graphics plot, but the solution only works if one had stored the original parameters. [Here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488548-Problem-with-Plots-or-Graphics-Device), instead, they suggest to do dev.off(), but that actually doesn't work for me.

Any idea?

Comment: Does it persist if you restart your R-session/Rstudio/your computer?

Comment: what is this `data <- [109    89  4405 ... ]`? are you really using R?

Comment: @rawr sorry, it should read: data <- c(109,89,...). I'm editing it now...

Comment: @Heroka if I restart the session, I get back to the original settings, so I can plot again. It seems what I was running previously messed with the settings. In fact, I was doing a histogram with hist, but getting the error: Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Comment: @user1651933 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410390/error-in-plot-new-figure-margins-too-large